# How to do a replace only on parts of string matching my regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

Lets' say I have this `html` code in my `String` variable;

```
String htmlCode = "<span class='test'>test</span>"+
+"<a href=\"http://foo.com?id=<span class='test'>test</span>\">link</a>";
```

The `htmlCode` variable would contain more links similar to that, plus it would also contain more `spans` similar to that.

I want to replace everything in between tags `<span` and `</span>` including those spans, but only if they are in `<a href` tag. Meaning that I don't want to replace the first `span` tag, but I want to replace the second one.

I know that regex can do that, but so far I was able to do this:

```
htmlCode = htmlCode.replaceAll("<span.*?</span>", "");
```

But how do I define that I want to replace it only if it occurs in the `<a>` tag? Plus is there a way to replace it including those `span` tags?

Comment: You should use a HTML parser for this purpose, like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). You could use the `a>span` selector and remove all the returned nodes.

Comment: Actually I am using a JSoup and I will use that. I was wondering though how would you do it with a string. Since it wouldn't have to be HTML, right? But thank you.

Comment: @BackSlash You should post that as answer.

Comment: Someone may (or may not) be able to design such a regex. Then you will realize it doesn't apply to nested `span` and/or nested `a` tags...

Comment: @Pshemo We have all been joked :) Look at the code, the span is **not** *child* of the `a` tag :) JSoup will do nothing here with the `a>span` selector

Comment: @BackSlash `href=\"http://foo.com?id=<span class='test'>test</span>\"` It doesn't make sense. Who does that?

Comment: @Pshemo we do it for a merge field in our system, that span value is then replaced by a string value. However, when it is in PDF file it is not replaced and link doesn't work. Therefore I need to remove the span tags from the link.

Comment: @Pshemo It seems they do. Although I find this placeholding system a bit weird...

Comment: @backslash it is an Eloqua system of Oracle... pretty widely used. Wonders every day huh? Any idea for a solution?

Comment: @OndrejTokar Please, see if my answer can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to remove `span` tags from `href` value of your `a` tag.

In that case you can try with something like

```
String htmlCode = "<span class='test'>test</span>"
        + "<a href=\"http://foo.com?id=<span class='test'>test</span>\">link</a>"
        + "<a href=\"http://foo.com?id=test2\">link</a>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlCode);
System.out.println(doc);

for (Element el : doc.select("a[href*=<span]")){//select a with href which contains `<span`
    el.attr("href", Jsoup.parse(el.attr("href")).text());//sets new value for `href` attribute which will be 
    //parsed "http://foo.com?id=<span class='test'>test</span>" and text it represents
}

System.out.println("-----");
System.out.println(doc);
```

Output (before/after):

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <span class="test">test</span>
  <a href="http://foo.com?id=<span class='test'>test</span>">link</a>
  <a href="http://foo.com?id=test2">link</a>
 </body>
</html>
-----
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <span class="test">test</span>
  <a href="http://foo.com?id=test">link</a>
  <a href="http://foo.com?id=test2">link</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how will that `Jsoup.parse(el.attr("href")).text()` remove the `span` tag.

Comment: @OndrejTokar The `text()` method strips out tags from the parsed string, so it will remove `<span>` and `</span>`

Comment: @OndrejTokar `Jsoup.parse` returns `Document` which extends `Element` class and inherits from it `text()` method. You can find its documentation here: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text-- In short in returns only text which will be generated from stored HTML structure like `<b>hello<b><i>world</i>` will become `helloworld`. It kind of simulates what text you will see in browser.

Comment: I have used the other solution, but since it isn't here, I assume you did some kind of quiet agreement so I will accept your answer.

Comment: Is my question that bad it has a negative value? If you think it isn't that bad I would be grateful for +1 rating so I don't have it -1 ;/. Thanks

Comment: @OndrejTokar I didn't do anything, @BackSlash probably removed his solution since you claimed that it didn't work correctly. Later it was updated but he probably thinks that `Jsoup.parse(..).text()` is better than `replaceAll` so he decided to remove his answer. But that is only mu suspicions.

Comment: @OndrejTokar I removed my answer, because it used regexes to parse the `span` elements in the `href`. I think this answer is better

Comment: @OndrejTokar Your question is not bad, but people often get on tilt when they see someone trying to combine `HTML + regex` and they downvote automatically. I often agree with them, because of http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/1393766 which is also the reason for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766

Comment: @Pshemo thank you for the explanation. It is shame people are so negative without checking it better ... ;)